# Compound formula

Tags: arrays, excel

Why there is a difference between 'array' formula and simple index based compounding?

Six observations:

```
Cell(A1)  9.2%
Cell(A2)  9.1%
Cell(A3)  0.5%
Cell(A4)  -0.6%
Cell(A5)  1.9%
Cell(A6)  -0.5%
```

Initially, I used array to calculate compound rate using

```
={(product(A1:A6+)-1)^1/6}
```

I got 3.48%

But, I create an index using the growth rate above:

```
Cell(B1)  100.00
Cell(B2)  109.24
Cell(B3)  119.18
Cell(B4)  119.83
Cell(B5)  119.14
Cell(B6)  121.44
Cell(B7)  120.87
```

and,

```
=(B7/B1)^(1/6)-1
```

I get 3.21%

Why there is a difference?

Thank you,

Comment: The thing that strikes me is that you have rounded numbers in column A. But maybe that does not make any difference. Also you do `-1` at different places

Comment: I don't think that first formula should work at all, at least it doesn't when I try it in my version of excel. You'd need parentheses around `1/6`, `PRODUCT(A1:A6+)` should not have that plus in it and the `-1` is in the wrong place. You should also multiply (growth rate + 1), instead of the growth rates as you have them. From your data it's also not clear if the values are actually rounded or just formatted that way. The second formula is the correct way to calulcate a [CAGR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_annual_growth_rate).

Comment: Parenthesis around 1/6 solved the problem. Thank you. =(PRODUCT(A1:A6+1)^(1/6))-1